# Trying to understanding the proof of the fact that Kazhdan property (T) implies expanders.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to trying to understanding the proof of the fact that Kazhdan property (T) implies expanders. This is a result of Grigory Margulis. It is stated in Proposition 3.3.1 on Page 30 of the book discrete groups, expander graphs, and invariant measures of Alexander Lubotzky.

[image]

Let $H=L^2(\Gamma/ N)$. Here $\Gamma$ is a finitely generated Kazhdan group $N$ is a finite index normal subgroup of $\Gamma$. Let $V = \Gamma/ N$. $L^2(\Gamma/ N)$ is the set of functions $f$ such that $||f||^2 = \sum_{x \in V} |f(x)|^2 < \infty$. $\Gamma$ acts on $H$ by $(\gamma f)(x) = f(x\gamma), x \in V, \gamma \in \Gamma$.

Let $H_0 = \{f \in H: \sum_{x\in V} f(x) = 0\}$. How to show that $H=H_0 \oplus \mathbb{C} \chi_V$ as a $\Gamma$-module? Why the action of $\Gamma$ on $V$ is transitive implies that the only $\Gamma$-invariant functions on $V$ are the constants $\mathbb{C} \chi_{V}$? Why then it follows that $H_0$ does not contain the trivial representation? Why $\Gamma$ is Kazhdan implies that $H_0$ does not have almost invariant functions? Thank you very much.

Comment: This question is, I think, fits better in overflow, or write directly to Alex asking him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is quite obvious if you look at it closely. The group $\Gamma$ acts on $V$ (via left multiplication) through the subgroup $\Gamma/N$ of the full permutation group $S_n$, where $n=|V|$, acting by permuting the elements of $V$. Now, $S_n$ clearly preserves $H_0$. It also preserves the constant function $\chi_V$. Now, given any function $f$ on $V$ you consider the difference 
$$
\bar f= f-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{x\in V} f(x)
$$ 
By construction $\bar f$ is in $H_0$, while $f- \bar f$ is a constant function, which, thus, belongs to ${\mathbb C} \chi_V$. Hence, we obtained the required direct sum decomposition of $H$ which is invariant under $S_n$ and, hence, under $\Gamma$.

Comment: thank you very much. I think that $\bar{f}=f-\sum_{x\in V} f(x)$.

Comment: @LJR: No, the formula is correct: You have to subtract the average, not the sum. Just try it in the case of the constant function $f$.